# Pass in implicit wait to expected conditions like stalenessOf?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We can pass in a timeout for a failing expected condition:

```
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(elementThatIsNotStale), 3000, 'Error: Element was found in the dom');
```

Can we pass in a value to override the implicit timeout that is currently being used on success?
I.e., I would like to make sure an element is not attached to the dom, but I would not like to wait for the 30s that our implicit timeout is set to. I would like too pass in both the fail and the pass timer:

```
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(elementThatIsStale), 3000, 3000, 'Error: Element was found in the dom');
```

This way it only checks for 3 seconds, regardless of pass or fail, before returning the results.

Is there a way to pass in an implicit timeout override?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait), `browser.wait()` only accepts 3 parameters:

- expected condition function
- timeout value
- optional timeout message

There is no way to change the implicit timeout through `browser.wait()`. You may try playing around with implicit wait timeout via [`implicitlyWait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Timeouts.prototype.implicitlyWait), not tested:

```
browser.implicitlyWait(3000);
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(elm), 3000, 'Error: Element was found in the dom');
browser.implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT);  // back to a default value
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the implicit wait to a very low value when checking negative cases (not present/not displayed), then, wait for your condition, and, then, set the implicit wait back to its original value.

Something like this:

```
browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(NO_IMPLICIT_WAIT);
browser.waitUntil(EC.stalenessOf(ele), message, NEGATIVE_WAIT); 
browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT);
```

where:

DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT is the default timeout that the driver waits before every element() call
NO_IMPLICIT_WAIT is a low value like zero 
NEGATIVE_WAIT is the timeout to be used when waiting for an element to become not present/not displayed